# Как построить график / таблицу распределения переменной по годам?

Tags: python, python-3.x, структуры-данных, pandas

Дан набор панельных данных:

```
merged1
Out[16]: 
             pid  syear                        pgsbil  \
0            101   1984        [3] Fachhochschulreife   
1         400802   1984       [1] Hauptschulabschluss 
     ...    ...                           ...   
478330    455601   2012         [5] Anderer Abschluss   
478331  31433901   2012                    [4] Abitur
```

Переменная `pid` обозначает идентификатор опрошенного человека и `syear` - год в котором проведён опрос.

Я построил несколько статистик, чтобы посмотреть сколько человек и в какие годы участвовали в опросе:

```
Q = merged1.groupby('pid')['syear'].value_counts()
Out[17]:
pid       syear
101       1984     1
          1985     1
          1986     1
          1987     1
          1988     1
          1989     1
102       1984     1
```

Теперь я могу видеть, что данные для респондента 101 доступны на протяжение 6 лет (1984 - 1989).
На основе этой переменной я не могу построить гистограмму, где по оси Х, были бы отложены года а по оси У, `pid` респондента. Проблема в том, что некоторые опросы проводились с разной периодичностью. И даже если отобразить количество лет доступных для анализа:

```
Z = merged1.groupby('pid')['syear'].count()
Z = Z.sort_values(ascending=0)
Out[19]: 
pid
493401      29
152801      29
151901      29
            ..
30303201     1
35008702     1
```

То я не смогу видеть или узнать равномерность распределения данных `pid` за разные года, чтобы подготовить набор данных за максимально длительный период. Опросы проводятся не равномерно, поэтому некоторые переменные могут встречаться раз в два года.

Поэтому, как мне построить график распределения или таблицу, чтобы посмотреть по каким годам есть `pid` данные? Чтобы увидеть, какие года доступны для каждого `pid`.

Comment: не совсем понятна задача - надо узнать для каких лет для каждого `pid` отсутствуют данные?

Comment: еще мне кажется, что при достаточно большом количестве `pid` (более десятка) [гистограммы](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html#histograms) визуально будут сильно наложены друг на друга и не будут нести полезной нагрузки

Comment: Вы верно подметели, поэтому я пытаюсь как то сделать матрицу или таблицу. Где строки например это года, столбцы это pid. На гистограмме было бы наглядней но все данные таким образом туда не поместятся. Поэтому я думал о таблице сводной или матрице, из которой потом можно вытянуть данные в определённом интервале для графика.

Comment: не знаю что это даст при большом кол-ве `pid`, но сделать это достаточно просто: `df.pivot_table(index='syear', columns='pid', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)`

Comment: Теперь можно вытащить года где есть пробелы (т.е. значение в клетке ноль).

Comment: нужны только те года где __все__ значения в строке == 0?

Comment: Я не так выразился, я имел в виду что можно теперь вычислить где единицы идут не подряд, если такое имеет место быть. Я хотел построить такую таблицу как инструмент для обнаружения прерываний в последовательности как:  1 0 1 0 1 0. Отражающих факт того что интервью проходил раз в два года.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно посчитать число уникальных `pid` для каждого года:

```
In [28]: df
Out[28]:
    pid  syear
0   101   1984
1   101   1985
2   101   1986
3   102   2002
4   103   1984
5   103   1985
6   103   1986
7   104   1984
8   104   1985
9   104   1986
10  105   2015
11  106   2002

In [29]: df.groupby('syear').pid.nunique().to_frame('uniq_pids').reset_index()
Out[29]:
   syear  uniq_pids
0   1984          3
1   1985          3
2   1986          3
3   2002          2
4   2015          1
```

и построить соотв. график:

```
In [30]: import matplotlib

In [31]: %matplotlib
Using matplotlib backend: TkAgg

In [32]: df.groupby('syear').pid.nunique().to_frame('uniq_pids').plot.bar(rot=0)
Out[32]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x98fc358>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Pivoted:

```
In [34]: df.pivot_table(index='syear', columns='pid', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)
Out[34]:
pid    101  102  103  104  105  106
syear
1984     1    0    1    1    0    0
1985     1    0    1    1    0    0
1986     1    0    1    1    0    0
2002     0    1    0    0    0    1
2015     0    0    0    0    1    0
```